# 201 Created or 303 See Other after a POST request

Tags: rest

From a RESTful interface, what should be the best status code after a successful POST action?

- **201 Created**
- **303 See Other**

Note: considering in the HTTP server answer, the `Location` key can be present.

I'm confused. Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the POST request created a new resource successfully, you should return `201 Created` with the resource URI provided in the `Location` header.

You can return `303 See Other` in response to a POST when the resource isn't created immediately, like there's an asynchronous task responsible for it, and you want to redirect the client to some other URI where he can monitor the current status of the task.

Comment: @cdeszaq 204 is No Content. I think you mean 202 Accepted. Yes, you can use the 202 Accepted, but you need to return the URI in the Location header anyway.

Comment: Ah, yes, typoed it. My point was that a 202 response is _explicitly_ for async cases, which is what you described in yout 303 description, where a 303 is more general. I usually prefer to use a more specific code when one is available.

Answer (score 1):

`201 Created` says "*the resource is created and here's the URL of that resource*".

`303 See Other` says "*nothing went wrong and you should check this URL for more information*".

The primary distinction is that you would expect a conforming client to *always* `GET` the URL from the `Location` header in the case of a `303 See Other`.  You would only expect a `201 Created` to result in a `GET` on the URL if the client decides they need to fetch the resource from the server.

I would generally advise against sending a `303 See Other` for anything but web forms or if you have developed a multi-stage API, where you must perform subsequent requests after the first.